# How to add unique value to mongoose subdocument with nestjs?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I want to convert a mongoose schema from my express api to nest js.

```js
const levelSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

export type LevelDocument = Level & Document;

@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
})
export class Level {
  @Prop({
    type: [
      {
        locale: { type: String, enum: ["fr", "en"] },
        title: { type: String, unique: true },
      },
    ],
  })
  translations: object[];

  @Prop({ default: false })
  visibility: Boolean;
}

export const LevelSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Level);
```

It works as expected but for some reason I'm not able to add unique key for the title ? I do not have any error, it just seems to ignore the `unique: true` rule.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a difference between your express schema and NestJS schema. Please be more specific.
Second thing is, your schema is working perfectly for me.

[image: Indexig]

And it throwing error when I am trying to duplicate title field.

[image]

Try reindexing the collection manually or drop the collection and restart the server.